# streamlit: Your system has an unsupported version of sqlite3. Chroma requires sqlite3 >= 3.35.0

Tags: python, streamlit, chromadb

I previously deployed an app on **Streamlit Cloud** that utilized `chromadb`.

The app worked fine in the past. However, today I encountered a new error (as indicated in the title) and the app has stopped functioning.

I attempted to troubleshoot based on [solutions from the Streamlit forum](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/issues-with-chroma-and-sqlite/47950) and performed the following steps sequentially:

1. Updated the `requirements.txt` file by adding `pysqlite3-binary`.
2. Added the following three lines of code at the top of `app.py`:

```py
__import__('pysqlite3')
import sys

sys.modules['sqlite3'] = sys.modules.pop('pysqlite3')
```

After **rebooting** my app, I discovered the new error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite3'
Traceback:
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 552, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/mount/src/docgpt-streamlit/app.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pysqlite3
```

Subsequently, I tried adding `pysqlite3` again to `requirements.txt`, but the error persisted.

According to the **logs** from **manage app**, I observed that Streamlit did not perform a **re-pip install** action.

[image]

Could this be causing the pysqlite error? If so, how can I correctly enable the Streamlit app to automatically pip install due to my updated `requirements.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into something similar not on Streamlit Cloud but on a docker container. I SSHed in and while my python version was fine, it was running an older sqlite for some reason:

```
Python 3.11.3

>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.version
'2.6.0'
```

It turns out that I was running an older version of debian (bullseye), which [Chroma's troubleshooting doc advises against](https://docs.trychroma.com/troubleshooting#sqlite), so I upped the image to `python:3.11.5-bookworm` and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I did this and it worked for me:

1. Install `pysqlite3-binary` using: `pip3 install pysqlite3-binary`
2. Then add below 3 lines in your code file where you have defined `Chromadb`

Credits:
I got this answer from here: [Issues with chroma and sqlite](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/issues-with-chroma-and-sqlite/47950/5)

Note: Doesn't matter if you are using `django`, `flask` or `fastapi`. It should work regardless.

```
__import__('pysqlite3')
import sys
sys.modules['sqlite3'] = sys.modules.pop('pysqlite3')
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I've solved this problem.

The streamlit app will not re-install module even you **reboot**.

Therefore, I deploy the app:

1. Delete app.
2. ReNew app.

Then the module will re-install.

Comment: Adding `pysqlite3` to `requirements.txt` in my case resulted in error. Just `pysqlite3-binary` and the lines of code did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

maybe the version of sqlite3 is too old in your python folder.
you can find it in python/DDLs/sqlite3.dll, You can right-click with your mouse, select Properties, and in the pop-up box, select Details to view the version information.

fix:
download the new version from https://www.sqlite.org/download.html and replace it. and try it again. Maybe it will be OK.

by the way, my os is windows

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issues when I deployed my app on Streamlit cloud. This's my solution.

1. *Why errors?*

- My environment in local is Window 10 and my app doesn't require pysqlite3-binary when I use ChromaDB.
- But when I deployed on streamlit cloud, the env is Linux and I have a issue like that.

2. *My solutions*.

- add `pysqlite3-binary` in to file `requirements.txt`.
- add

```
__import__('pysqlite3')
import sys
sys.modules['sqlite3'] = sys.modules.pop('pysqlite3')
```

in the first lines code. My version is

```
streamlit==1.28.1
chromadb==0.4.17
```

And in my case, it runs successfully.

Hope my solution can be useful for you.

Comment: How did you add  pysqlite3-binary? which version?

Comment: my pysqlite3-binary version is 0.5.2. I installed and import as above.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue using Python 3.11 as the image:

```
FROM python:3.11-slim-bullseye
```