# chromadb fails to load index on Azure App Service created using Linux OS, Python 3.11 runtime due to sqlite3 version incompatibility

Tags: azure, sqlite, azure-web-app-service, sqlite3-python, chromadb

As we know - [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) is typically part of python's standard library

We did a comparison for sqlite3 version found b/w Azure App Service and Local Windows Machine, while both having same Python 3.11 version

Created an Azure App Service with below options:

```
OS: Linux
Runtime: Python 3.11 (3.11.4)
App Service Plan: Free
Region: East US
```

Published this code snippet wrapped inside a web app on `App Service`:

```
import sqlite3
print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)
```

We executed the same code in local windows machine ([Python 3.11](https://www.python.org/downloads/)) as well.

The results are as follows:

- `Sqlite3` version on `Azure App Service` is: `3.34.1` which is pretty old, Follow this [link](https://www.sqlite.org/chronology.html)
- `Sqlite3` version on `local windows machine` is: `3.39.4` which is still recent, if not the latest

Because of this `version gap`, certain library such as `chromadb` which needs `sqlite3 >= 3.35.0` fails to create index on `Azure App Service`.

Could someone explain this gap in `sqlite3` version b/w `Azure App Service` vs `Local Windows` (using open-source [python](https://www.python.org/downloads/) distribution), despite both having same `Python 3.11` version, and how could we upgrade `sqlite3` version on `App Service`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had a similar problem deploying a chromaDB instance on streamlit. The solutions provided in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76958817/streamlit-your-system-has-an-unsupported-version-of-sqlite3-chroma-requires-sq) finally got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this issue. The steps are listed at the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1369017/azure-app-service-has-older-sqlite3-version-3-34-1

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Azure App service used Sqllite version - 3.34.1 when I deployed a sample streamlit app with SQLlite in Azure app service according to the comment by James, Refer below:-

[image]

According to my SO thread answer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76845832/why-does-adding-chromadb-in-requirements-txt-cause-failure-in-azure-deployment/76849353#)** in order for chromadb package to work, You need to Create your Azure Web app with Python 3.8 like below:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Python 3.8 is an older version, we prob. won't like downgrade python version just for the sake of this issue. but anyway. I've found the solution based on the hint from Microsoft community, kindly check out the link above